# Starting tomcat8 failing in Ubuntu docker

Tags: tomcat, docker

I ran the docker image

> docker.io/ubuntu

and installed tomcat8 with

> apt-get install tomcat8

When I start tomcat (`service tomcat8 start`) it fails but I cannot see any error message in `/var/log/tomcat8`.

I am not sure what to check and why it fails. Any idea how to progress?
Thanks,
V.

************* UPDATE **************
All I did was only to start the container with

> docker run  -p 3306:3306 -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -it 2a4cca5ac898

and installed tomcat with `apt-get install tomcat8` and start the tomcat8 as service (so no Dockerfile had to be used). I don't know how to start the tomcat8 in another way than service as the startup.sh fails.

> touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
>   /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh: 401: /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat8/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent

Comment: in docker containers you dont run services but oyu have to run your apps in foreground (not deamonized), you should also provide dockerfile and how you start it

Comment: hi @MazelTov, thanks! I updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

1. i think you should use the official image from tomcat https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/
2. if you need your ubuntu and install it your way
   you can start tomcat in ubuntu in foreground with

   ```
   /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh run
   ```

   i started ubuntu with `docker run -it ubuntu`
     then inside container do `apt update && apt install tomcat8 -y`, copy the config `mkdir -p /usr/share/tomcat8/conf && cp /etc/tomcat8/server.xml /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/server.xml` and then start the tomcat

Comment: Hi @MazelTov, thanks again. I tried it but got the following errors `WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/server.xml]
Feb 04, 2018 3:03:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.` I think I will try to install Tomcat8 from source...

Comment: it tells you it is missing config file, i updated my answer based on that

Comment: Hi @MazelTov, thanks again but I decided to download the zIP and use it.